# Circle Image View : Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

My app runs fine but when i open a menu item where i have a list of names, images, and links of their social media it crushes.

One thing i want to say that when i use normal Image view its works fine.so i think i have a problem with the circle image view.

circle image view dependency:

```
implementation 'com.alexzh:circleimageview:1.2.0'
```

here is a part of the circle image view..I have 8 more like this.

**XML FILE:**

```
         <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp">

                <com.alexzh.circleimageview.CircleImageView

                    android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"

                    android:layout_height="70dp"


                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/mdnazimuddin"
                    app:view_borderColor="@color/main_color"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="168dp">


                </com.alexzh.circleimageview.CircleImageView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/imageView7"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Md.Nazim Uddin"
                    app:fontFamily="@font/cantora_one" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView15"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/textView7"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="FULL-STACK DEVELOPER AND SYSTEM ADMINISTRATOR"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    app:fontFamily="@font/cantora_one" />


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/textView15"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/nazim_fb"
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_facebook" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/nazim_linkedIN"
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"

                        android:src="@drawable/ic_linkedin" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/nazim_twiter"
                        android:layout_width="25dp"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"

                        android:src="@drawable/ic_twitter" />


                </LinearLayout>


            </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**JAVA FILE**

public class OurTeam extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_our_team);
    findViewById(R.id.nazim_fb).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked_img("https://www.facebook.com/rexmduddin?_rdc=1&_rdr");
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.nazim_linkedIN).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked_img("https://www.linkedin.com/authwall?trk=gf&trkInfo=AQH15P03jemzVwAAAXKeIu7I9DDJacpBFMc6vymN3OFiy00rIk3faRgAvHtnMb2NEWi3PSGMeItu-h2IBcAqk44WQgenlGEjkJ5Fm_ECAO99c6Ty_dRptchPlikNLl5TUoEYsR0=&originalReferer=https://demo3.thebitcode.com/?fbclid=IwAR3U4DTxNrRvsHaodsEXtDbivihvEImCUh8nYNG6w9bHJIYFoH6rry9bOLA&sessionRedirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fin%2Frexmdnazim%2F");
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.nazim_twiter).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked_img("https://twitter.com/rexmdnazim");
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.shourov_fb).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked_img("https://www.facebook.com/shourov.cse1810");
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.shourov_linked).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked_img("https://www.linkedin.com/in/shourov-cse-1810?fbclid=IwAR0QzpCOQkYKb7bhmG3oHrt1zHIK5ldKaej9XRbb1qdKZ9ioXjt4ZWaLPIg");
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.shourov_twitter).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked_img("https://twitter.com/shourov_return0?fbclid=IwAR3BVTbP5K1fXnrtVh5J3SMUwADvAi7ATxSHK7fsxYkdD19ept0-Iml5_AQ");
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.hasan_fb).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked_img("\n" +
                    "https://www.facebook.com/mdhasibulhasan3137");
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.hasan_linked).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked_img("\n" +
                    "https://www.linkedin.com/authwall?trk=gf&trkInfo=AQET7KPSchtc6AAAAXLrwwDI0xHh1EV24g87XswfdW5N-TMpfzxNuEOwO8b4VfVxjJH6OOf2ISAvx4jmDz3GXCONHDNEWS_N99xh5g_e0QYVoCbqt8P_DHyl8wiHYrqPGJwCETY=&originalReferer=https://thebitcode.com/about-us/&sessionRedirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fin%2Fmdhasibulhasan3137%2F\n");
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.hasan_twittter).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked_img("\n" +
                    "https://twitter.com/mdhasibul_hasan");
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.akash_fb).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked_img(
                    "https://www.facebook.com/amir.akash2");
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.akssh_linked).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked_img(
                    "https://www.linkedin.com/authwall?trk=gf&trkInfo=AQGCdtaNTI0XuAAAAXLrw1a47xZaDOMvfS112R7d5GtnwhRTiua35Pm1sEAINDVDaZVkUvPTR_ucZH5ob_VGLWUjA9edWqb4FI-Bn3_GdyATFwwr8SRdLXsMIJD6Vs0ZFNhcjCA=&originalReferer=https://thebitcode.com/about-us/&sessionRedirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fin%2Famir-sohel-ab4290198%2F\n");
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.rabea_fb).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked_img(
                    "https://www.facebook.com/rabeya.anni.9");
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.rabeya_linked).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked_img(
                    "https://www.linkedin.com/authwall?trk=gf&trkInfo=AQErk7CY7RwomwAAAXLrxgY4xn_K8ZVzn1RMVhIcmMfXln_vp9Eyz8Hv06cjLSi0JFqNUQWf1YYFMmpREgqH7Jci-b1lZS7ELyzvny45SyTMxgVrfc6M9Eo_DXI8sUFJ30AVqXM=&originalReferer=https://thebitcode.com/about-us/&sessionRedirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fin%2Frabeya-anni-a61b2b197%2F");
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.sumaiya_fb).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked_img(
                    "https://www.facebook.com/sumaiya.islam.5015");
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.sumiya_twitter).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked_img(
                    "https://twitter.com/Sumaiya66668554");
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.sumaiya_linked).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked_img(
                    "https://www.linkedin.com/authwall?trk=gf&trkInfo=AQHtQRfwrugX3gAAAXLrxp6QlEDZJFciyLsF3KWhQ78Iu5uiesovLV7PP8U_OOp3rFiLBq5faMCUKLEft17Ewp2rIQRwnr7F5EY9ygqxtIKAbATGH1YE-QI1npGF0gHXPYslxL8=&originalReferer=https://thebitcode.com/about-us/&sessionRedirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fin%2Fsumaiya-islam-1531291ab%2F");
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.shofol_fb).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked_img(
                    "https://www.facebook.com/asikul.sofol");
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.shofol_linked).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked_img(
                    "https://www.linkedin.com/authwall?trk=gf&trkInfo=AQHoo4YpuYVrRgAAAXLrxAaAmpwGPJmg9TfxWiFl9YPWGg8EU0Q_zU_dxGQ1Ce7sHSJ92LdF83yNbLJHAYCNpQwxsqdjqf68WJzsYmPI_cWAYNfdRA6gbcAZ0sMXIt3Zkm4i87U=&originalReferer=https://thebitcode.com/about-us/&sessionRedirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fin%2Fmd-asikul-hossain-shofol-439819179%2F%2F");
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.shofol_twitter).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked_img("https://twitter.com/MShofol");
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.himel_fb).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked_img(
                    "https://www.facebook.com/hasibulislam.himel.12");
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.rabbi_fb).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked_img(
                    "https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100007277297662");
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.rabbi_twitter).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked_img(
                    "https://twitter.com/44salamrab");
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.rabbi_linked).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked_img(
                    "https://www.linkedin.com/authwall?trk=gf&trkInfo=AQHY2hB3sl4p9QAAAXLr6kOQmQyq1fw8WYTXbSEFlgFMnkg5D_Vgj4cbrhJXD_HPKut8hZwCW30byvS27y31l1PjrYtJFvN-BjX4hWGnrfzmwqpczJCGYepuJH5fAxZIZKOed-Y=&originalReferer=https://thebitcode.com/about-us/&sessionRedirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fin%2Fali-rabbi-50560618a%2F");
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.nahid_fb).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked_img(
                    "https://www.facebook.com/lh.nahid1");
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.nahid_linked).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked_img(
                    "https://www.linkedin.com/authwall?trk=gf&trkInfo=AQEg7T_BNwqx2wAAAXLrxRvYVE1fDxvdacjdjZm9PiKfbYHp8TEP5BTXpaLWKDOezrcmvNK4URkw_DMULcN5_yYBEl6n1tJk9QtkfPDaEF797eZL4AYoC6x9TNDzE2BPMgLTrL8=&originalReferer=https://thebitcode.com/about-us/&sessionRedirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fin%2Floman-hazra-nahid-7a1398175%2F");
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.nahid_twitter).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked_img("https://twitter.com/nahid_lh");
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.zb_fb).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked_img("https://www.facebook.com/zobaer53");
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.zb_linked).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked_img("https://www.linkedin.com/authwall?trk=gf&trkInfo=AQFc66rxAlR1RQAAAXLrxydIL00rYz9AjPafPKj-q6mv4PNkG8YfpsvBCy3e7G_4EZSfRM3-lVVIBIOOdKkPUvb1hl-neisHTdvzfBK2Ud_bxuh_4vhcsfN2nQaFvPYsYIx4n7k=&originalReferer=https://thebitcode.com/about-us/&sessionRedirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fin%2Fzobaer-hossain-27275b194");
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.nuhash_fb).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked_img(
                    "https://www.facebook.com/nuhash.rijvi.58");
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.nuhash_twitter).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked_img("https://twitter.com/nuhash_rijvi ");
        }
    });















}


public void clicked_img(String url) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

}

Here are my errors:

```
2020-06-25 21:34:18.427 6306-6334/com.labawsrh.aws.introscreen E/eglCodecCommon: GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1

2020-06-25 21:34:47.935 6306-6306/com.labawsrh.aws.introscreen E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.

2020-06-25 21:34:47.942 6306-6306/com.labawsrh.aws.introscreen E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.labawsrh.aws.introscreen, PID: 6306
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.alexzh.circleimageview.ItemSelectedListener.onUnselected(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
        at com.alexzh.circleimageview.CircleImageView.hidePressedRing(CircleImageView.java:433)
        at com.alexzh.circleimageview.CircleImageView.setPressed(CircleImageView.java:406)
        at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:13847)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:12513)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3000)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3000)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3000)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3000)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3000)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:440)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1830)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3400)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:398)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12752)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5106)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4909)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4585)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7092)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7061)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7022)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7195)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:186)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
2020-06-25 21:34:47.943 6306-6306/com.labawsrh.aws.introscreen E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:177)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:7166)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7218)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:690)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: It looks like your `CircleImageView`s all need to have [`ItemSelectedListener`s](https://github.com/AlexZhukovich/CircleImageView/blob/master/circleimageview/src/main/java/com/alexzh/circleimageview/ItemSelectedListener.java) set on them, because that class does not do a null check before trying to callback on its listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. View cannot define your Circle ImageView.
2. You are using null object, before using it check with **if(object != null)**

If you could share your .kt or .java class. We could say where it is throwing exception.